# What is best way to response Azure BLOB image from express without storing it on web server

Tags: node.js, express, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am searching for a solution that downloads documents from Azure BLOB and response it to the app user. I can not create public link as documents that are stored on Azure BLOB are private. So I created a route from where server authenticates the request and then response relevant document from Azure BLOB.

I google a lot but I didn't find any suitable solution.

I have tried below methods of Azure BLOB nodejs SDK.

```
let buffer = await blockBlobClient.downloadToBuffer()

let buffer = await blockBlobClient.download(0)
```

I am getting an object while using download method and buffer data while using downloadToBuffer method. But I am not able to response it using express without storing a file on the web server.